# PHPSESSID Cookie gets send multiple times

Tags: php, session-cookies

In my current application the PHPSESSID Cookie gets send multiple times. Here's a sample response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 11 Jun 2013 08:18:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.15-1~dotdeb.0
Set-Cookie: ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3; path=/ PHPSESSID=625qvi6328pdq2t7psh4t3voi6; path=/ PHPSESSID=625qvi6328pdq2t7psh4t3voi6; path=/ PHPSESSID=625qvi6328pdq2t7psh4t3voi6; path=/
Cache-Control: no-cache
x-debug-token: 9dcc688323f1dad273d4c8fc7117f405a52ce998
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

As you can see, there are three PHPSESSIDs.

I tried to reproduce this behavior with a single file with three `session_start();` calls:

```
<?php

session_start();
session_start();
session_start();
```

but the cookie was send only once.

Any idea how this could happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit. Somewhere deep in the legacy code was a [`session_commit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-commit.php) which was called multiple times.